# PHP and simplexml

Tags: php

i use php and simplexml, my probleme is "to add a attribute with for"
my code is:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$compteur;$i++)
    {
        $jeu->situation->question->choix->addChild('rep',"\n".$rep[$i]."\n");
        $jeu->situation->question->choix->rep->addAttribute('val',$i);

    }
```

Result:

```
                             <choix>
                <rep val="1">

                </rep>
                <rep>

                </rep>
            </choix>
```

he add just in a first  !!!

Comment: instead attribute @val i use for!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addChild()` returns the node that was added to the DOM, so do your attribute work on that

```
$child = $jeu->situation->question->choix->addChild('rep',"\n".$rep[$i]."\n");
$child->addAttribute('val', $i);
```